# Spring Boot application pending when trying to persist to SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, spring

I have a Spring Boot application which I'm trying to use in order to persist some data to a MSSQL instance running as a Docker container (just for dev purposes) on port 1434.

I have a `@Repository` class implementing from `CrudRepository`:

```
@Repository
public interface BookingRepository extends CrudRepository<Booking, Integer> {

}
```

And then a `@Service` class where I want to try and persist a booking:

```
public void process(Booking booking) throws IOException {
    bookingCreatedRepository.save(booking);
    log.info("After the save"); // this line is never reached
}
```

The thing is that the `log.info` line in the service snippet above is never reached. If I open up the debugger and try to force the save via an evaluation of that statement, the operation never finishes.

There are no exceptions, no timeout, nothing. The application just stops at that point.

My `application.properties` file:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=Password12#
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1434;databaseName=Reporting
spring.jpa.database=sql_server
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
spring.jpa.database-platform=SQL_SERVER
```

Also, my dependencies are the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.16.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out, but it's got nothing to do with what I describer per se.

I was using AWS Kinesis via the official AWS Kinesis SDK, which was apparently blocking the thread where the `.save()` was supposed to happen. I guess the moral of the story is to check for the thread being blocked.